# Swift animation freezes when page loads, swiftui

Tags: animation, swiftui, lottie

I use a `Lottie` animation in `SwiftUI`. Sometimes, when pages loads, animation freezes for a couple of seconds. I would like to know if it is possible to dispatch task or do anything in order to have the animation never freeze. File is stores locally in the app, `Lottie` is displayed in `SwiftUI`:

```
if condition { LottieLoading() }

import SwiftUI import Lottie

struct LottieLoading: UIViewRepresentable {

    func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<LottieLoading>) -> UIView {
        let view = UIView(frame: .zero)
        
        
        
        let animationView = AnimationView()
        let animationLottie = Animation.named("progress_relat")
        
        animationView.animation = animationLottie
        animationView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        animationView.loopMode = .loop
        animationView.animationSpeed = 2
        animationView.play()
        
        
        
        animationView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(animationView)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            animationView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor),
            animationView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor)
        ])
        
        return view
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIViewType, context: Context) {
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem might be in the fact that you're calling `play` in `makeUIView`. Have you tried calling `play` in `updateUIView` instead?

Comment: Thanx for the proposition. It is called inside makeUIView because it has to be done from the start. I got some updates on updateUIVIew (is animated) . Even if the update gives me not animating, trying to pause and play the animation on updateUIView doesn t change anything